# Replace certain spaces to tabs - delimiters

Tags: regex, r, dataframe, delimiter

I have one column `data.frame` where some spaces should be delimiters some just a space.

```
#input data
dat <- data.frame(x=c("A 2 2 textA1 textA2 Z1",
                      "B 4 1 textX1 textX2 textX3 Z2",
                      "C 3 5 textA1 Z3"))
#                               x
# 1        A 2 2 textA1 textA2 Z1
# 2 B 4 1 textX1 textX2 textX3 Z2
# 3               C 3 5 textA1 Z3
```

Need to convert it to 5 column `data.frame`:

```
#expected output
output <- read.table(text="
A   2   2   textA1 textA2   Z1
B   4   1   textX1 textX2 textX3    Z2
C   3   5   textA1  Z3",sep="\t")
#   V1 V2 V3                   V4 V5
# 1  A  2  2        textA1 textA2 Z1
# 2  B  4  1 textX1 textX2 textX3 Z2
# 3  C  3  5               textA1 Z3
```

Essentially, need to change 1st, 2nd, 3rd, and the last space to a tab (or any other delimiter if it makes it easier to code).

Playing with `regex` is not giving anything useful yet...

**Note1:** In real data I have to replace 1st, 2nd, 3rd,...,19th and the last spaces to tabs.
**Note2:** There is no pattern in `V4`, text can be anything.
**Note3:** Last column is one word text with variable length.

Comment: Try `v1 <- gsub("^([^ ]+)\\s+([^ ]+)\\s+([^ ]+)\\s+", '\\1,\\2,\\3,', dat$x);read.table(text=sub(' +(?=[^ ]+$)', ',', v1, perl=TRUE), sep=",")`

Comment: Thanks @akrun, please add your comment as an answer.

Comment: @akrun see Note, your solution would still work, just need to extend to `'\\1,\\2,...\\\19'...`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try

```
v1 <- gsub("^([^ ]+)\\s+([^ ]+)\\s+([^ ]+)\\s+", '\\1,\\2,\\3,', dat$x)
read.table(text=sub(' +(?=[^ ]+$)', ',', v1, perl=TRUE), sep=",")
#  V1 V2 V3                   V4 V5
#1  A  2  2        textA1 textA2 Z1
#2  B  4  1 textX1 textX2 textX3 Z2
#3  C  3  5               textA1 Z3
```

Or an option inspired from @Tensibai's post

```
n <- 3
fpat <- function(n){
   paste0('^((?:\\w+ ){', n,'})([\\w ]+)\\s+(\\w+)$')
}

read.table(text=gsub(fpat(n), "\\1'\\2' \\3", dat$x, perl=TRUE))
#  V1 V2 V3                   V4 V5
#1  A  2  2        textA1 textA2 Z1
#2  B  4  1 textX1 textX2 textX3 Z2
#3  C  3  5               textA1 Z3
```

For more columns,

```
 n <- 19
 v1 <- "A 24 34343 212 zea4 2323 12343 111 dsds 134d 153xd 153xe 153de 153dd dd dees eese tees3 zee2 2353 23335 23353 ddfe 3133"

 read.table(text=gsub(fpat(n), "\\1'\\2' \\3", v1, perl=TRUE), sep='')
 # V1 V2    V3  V4   V5   V6    V7  V8   V9  V10   V11   V12   V13   V14 V15
 #1  A 24 34343 212 zea4 2323 12343 111 dsds 134d 153xd 153xe 153de 153dd  dd
 #  V16  V17   V18  V19                   V20  V21
 #1 dees eese tees3 zee2 2353 23335 23353 ddfe 3133
```

Comment: Sorry I can't upvote twice, the edit is brilliant (I didn't had the idea to make the pattern within a function, and the gsub call to take advantage of the quoted interpretation of read.table is great) I still have to learn

Comment: @Tensibai  The edit was only possible because of your clever code.  I was thinking about for some time, but didn't get it right.  Thanks for the support.

Answer (score 6):

With a variable number of columns:

```
library(stringr)
cols <- 3
m <- str_match(dat$x, paste0("((?:\\w+ ){" , cols , "})([\\w ]+) (\\w+)"))
t <- paste0(gsub(" ", "\t", m[,2]), m[,3], "\t", m[,4])

> read.table(text=t,sep="\t")
  V1 V2 V3                   V4 V5
1  A  2  2        textA1 textA2 Z1
2  B  4  1 textX1 textX2 textX3 Z2
3  C  3  5               textA1 Z3
```

Change the number of columns to tell how many you wish before.
For the regex:

- `((?:\\w+ ){3})` Capture the 3 repetitions `{3}` of the non capturing group  `(?:\w+ )` which matche at least one alphanumeric character `w+` followed by a space
- `([\\w ]+) (\w+)` capture the free text from alphanumeric char or space `[\w ]+` followed by a space and the capture the last word with `\w+`

Once that done, paste the 3 parts  returned by `str_match` taking care of replacing the spaces in the first group `m[,2]` by tabs.

`m[,1]` is the whole match so it's unused here.

---

Old answer:

A basic one matching based on a fixed number of fields:

```
> read.table(text=gsub("(\\w+) (\\w+) (\\w+) ([\\w ]+) (\\w+)$","\\1\t\\2\t\\3\t\\4\t\\5",dat$x,perl=TRUE),sep="\t")
  V1 V2 V3                   V4 V5
1  A  2  2        textA1 textA2 Z1
2  B  4  1 textX1 textX2 textX3 Z2
3  C  3  5               textA1 Z3
```

Add as many (\w+) you wish before, and increase the number of \1 (back references)

Answer (score 3):

Here can be one twisted way to go that will work whatever the number of "words" you have (and that works on your data); it's based on the number of alphanum characters in your "words" compared to the number of alphanum characters in the other fields:

```
res <- gsub("\\w{3,}\\K\\t(?=\\w{3,})", " ", gsub(" ", "\t", dat$x), perl=T)
res
# [1] "A\t2\t2\ttextA1 textA2\tZ1"        "B\t4\t1\ttextX1 textX2 textX3\tZ2" "C\t3\t5\ttextA1\tZ3"

read.table(text=res, sep="\t")
#  V1 V2 V3                   V4 V5
#1  A  2  2        textA1 textA2 Z1
#2  B  4  1 textX1 textX2 textX3 Z2
#3  C  3  5               textA1 Z3
```

***EDIT: A completely different way to go, only based on the number of the spaces `k` you need to replace before the last one:***

```
k <- 3 # in your example
res <- sapply(as.character(dat$x), 
              function(x, k){
                 pos_sp <- gregexpr(" ", x)[[1]]
                 x <- strsplit(x, "")[[1]]
                 if (length(pos_sp) > k+1) pos_sp <- pos_sp[c(1:k, length(pos_sp))]
                 x[pos_sp] <- "\t"
                 x <- paste(x, collapse="")
               }, k=k)

read.table(text=res, sep="\t")
#   V1 V2 V3                   V4 V5
# 1  A  2  2        textA1 textA2 Z1
# 2  B  4  1 textX1 textX2 textX3 Z2
# 3  C  3  5               textA1 Z3
```